# How to calculate the volume between two cylinders

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am asked to calculate the volume between the two cylinder : $x^2+y^2=1$ and $x^2+z^2=1$

So my assumption here that the limit of $y$ and $z$ must be equal, and we are looking on the unit circle so the integral needs to be:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{1} 1 dx\,dy\,dz$$

but the answer is just one and this is doesn't make sense (intuitively) because the radius it self is 1 and what I imagine in my head is that the marked domain is the line between $x=1$ and $x=-1$

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the limit of $y$ and $z$ must be equal, and we are looking on the unit circle"

Comment: This is a common mistake when tackling multiple integrals for the first time. Specifically for triple integrals, the innermost bounds represent *surfaces* that bound the solid, then the next bounds represent *curves* then the last bounds are only points. In this case what do the *surfaces* $x=0,1$ represent and why are they incorrect for this problem?

Comment: Note that the bounds of an integral will only be numbers (independent of $x,y,z$) if the region of integration is a rectangle, which is not the case for this problem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi ok I think I understand why it wrong, they represent a rectangle of width 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've attached a plot of the problem shown in the $xy$-plane. The red circle is a circular cross section of the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ where $z=0$, and the blue rectangle is a rectangular cross section of the cylinder $x^2+z^2=1$ where $z=0$ as well. We can see here then that we might choose to integrate from $z=-1$ to $z=1$, and we can determine the bounds of the $x$ and $y$ integrals by using the boundary conditions for the cylinders:

$$
x^2+z^2=1 \\
x=\pm \sqrt{1-z^2}
$$

and

$$
x^2+y^2=1\\
y=\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$

So, the integral is:

$$
\int_{-1}^{1}\int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\text{d}y\text{d}x\text{d}z
$$

[image: Plot of the problem]

Comment: Can you explain how we see from the picture that we can integrate $z$ between 1 and -1?

Comment: It is a little ambiguous, you're correct. When we are solving for the volume, we need to get a number: we shouldn't have variables like $x$, $y$, or $z$ in the result. Thus, the leftmost integral should integrate over a constant interval. We know from $x^2+z^2=1$ that the bounds on $z$ are $\pm 1$, which is why I chose those bounds. Then, from the picture, we get an idea for the bounds on $x$ and $y$. In short: the picture doesn't tell the whole story, it just makes our goal of finding the bounds easier, but you'll still have to use thought outside of the picture to solve the problem.

Comment: As an additional note, you could have just as easily said that $x$ goes from $-1$ to $1$, and then solved for the variable bounds on $z$ and $y$.

Comment: Ok, thanks! do you have any recomendation about a source that helping in vsiualize how the problems are looks in the space? I feel that what is stops me from getting full understand is the understanding how the problem looks like

Comment: Computer algebra software is your best bet. If your school provides computer algebra software, I would recommend that. Otherwise, SageMath is a nice free, open-source, python-based computer algebra system that I often use, although I've never used it to plot 3D graphs.